# Как реализовать липкий элемент который потом исчезает?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно реализовать липкий элемент только на мобильном разрешении.
Т.е при мобильном разрешении "База - Стандарт - Как на Картинке" скользят поверх всей таблицы и когда доходят до таких же значений внизу таблицы - они исчезают.

Пример: [click](https://goodstone.ru/msk/gazobeton/proekt-gb-224/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, может есть какие-то плагины или пример кода.

Comment: Медиа-запросы + `position: sticky` + `bottom: 0px`. Или не 0...

Comment: Данный липкий элемент должен появляться в начале таблицы и пропадать в её конце. Думаю без JS тут не обойтись.

Comment: Почему не обойтись? Вы недооцениваете возможности липкого позиционирования

Answer (score 1):

Грустно, что я не убедил Вас использовать липкое позиционирование через `position: sticky`. Это работает именно так, как вы описываете, без JS и плагинов:

```css
.container {
  margin: 20em 1em;
  position: relative;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr {
  background: yellow;
}

tr.last {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Строка</td></tr>
      <tr class="last"><td>Строчка-прилипучка</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Чтобы ограничиться мобильным разрешением, нужно обернуть правило в медиа-запрос:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .last {
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение с помощью jquery плагина http://scrollmagic.io/